# Can't perform no password authentication ssh

Tags: ssh

After creating pair of keys and sending public key to server via ssh-copy-id i'm still not able to log in with no password

The output from ssh -v user@host

- debug1: Found key in /home/pumba/.ssh/known_hosts:1
- debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
- debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
- debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
- debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
- debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
- debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
- debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
- debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_rsa
- debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
- debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
- debug1: Trying private key: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_ecdsa
- debug1: Trying private key: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_ed25519
- debug1: Next authentication method: password

Answer (score 1):

Debugging SSH Passwordless authentications:

**Run in detailed debug mode -vvv**

> ssh -vvv user@host

**Run with a specific key**

> ssh -i private_key user@host

**Check File Permissions**

> ~./ssh permissions should be 700
>
> ~./ssh should be owned by your account
>
> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys permissions should be 600
>
> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys should be owned by your account

Permissions in client:

> /.ssh/config permissions should be 600
>
> ~/.ssh/id_* permissions should be 600

**Check if your private key matches with public key**

> Local: ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> Server: cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: debug1: Trying private key: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/pumba/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory  -- this is what i get, when i run ssh in detailed mode

Comment: Where is your private key stored? try to directly inject your private with "ssh -i /home/pumba/<private_key> user@host"

Comment: keys are strored in ~/.ssh and after executing this command is still get to enter password

Comment: Please check your keys and see if it matches with key in authorized keys, the error clearly says "there is no such file or directory found"